# Edit open Excel sheet from Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

How can I insert a row and populate the cells in and Excel sheet that is already open programmatically from MS Access?

Comment: Record a macro, check the code, and either use early or lat binding. Late is best.

Comment: If you told us how the spreadsheet is opened, what references you set to open it... give us more detail.  Have a look at this question, it shows thought has gone into the question and effort has been put into telling us where the problem occurs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923588/powershell-catch-exception-codes-for-wmi-query

Comment: In Access I used the command docmd.outputto acoutputtable to create the Excel sheet from a table. When the command completes I have the sheet open on the screen. I now want to insert a row and add additional headings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility to do it:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
    Excel.Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = "Test"

End Sub
```

Just reference the other workbook using `.Workbooks` and the path of the other workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of going about it is to create a new workbook directly out of access and then populate it:

```
'Open a new instance of Excel to be used and run without being visible
Dim xls As Excel.Application
Set xls = New Excel.Application
```

This code opens a new instance of excel and an empty workbook.